# Displaying content of form input element in another field using javascript onFocus event

Tags: javascript

PROBLEM: I want Javascript to calculate the sum of two numeric inputs from a user and display the sum in the third field immediately the user tabs into or clicks on the field. 
ERROR: Firefox, Chrome and Safari all display zero when the third field is on focus; however, in fairness to Firefox, it reluctantly displays the required result after refreshing; others don't. I suspect an error in my code which I cannot identify, please help.

```js
        window.onload = function() {
            var input1 = document.getElementById('bk').value;
            var input2 = document.getElementById('softw').value;
            input1 = Number(input1); // convert input to number
            input2 = Number(input2);
            input3 = input1 + input2; // Sum the inputs
            document.getElementById('total').onfocus = function() {
                document.getElementById('total').value = input3;
                return input3;
            }
        }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div id='fm_div'>
        <form action="#" method="GET" id='form1'>
            <p>Qty of Books:
                <input type="text" name="bkqty" id='bk'>
            </p>
            <p>Qty of Software:
                <input type="text" name="software" id='softw'>
            </p>
            <p>Total:
                <input type='text' id='total'>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type='submit' value='send' id='submit'>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting **`input1`** and **`input2`** on window load  function. But the textboxes will not have any value on load. change your window.onload function as below

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('total').onfocus = function() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('bk').value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById('softw').value;
    input1 = Number(input1); // convert input to number
    input2 = Number(input2);
    input3 = input1 + input2; // Sum the inputs
    document.getElementById('total').value = input3;
    return input3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='fm_div'>
  <form action="#" method="GET" id='form1'>
    <p>Qty of Books:
      <input type="text" name="bkqty" id='bk'>
    </p>
    <p>Qty of Software:
      <input type="text" name="software" id='softw'>
    </p>
    <p>Total:
      <input type='text' id='total'>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type='submit' value='send' id='submit'>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```